# Best workaround for using "state" without react/vue in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

I may be overthinking the issue here.

I have a for...of loop in main, that I need to break out of when a button is clicked. The best I could come up with was this.

- I created a new store
- I initialise the variable to false
- I check the value from the store first thing in the for loop.
- I click a button on the front end, which changes the variable's value in store to true
- for will break on the next iteration, which is my end goal.

What I'm not too keen is that electron-store is for persistent data, and not really a "state" management package. So one would have to clear any unnecessary variables on load.

main.js

```
const store = new Store();

store.set('foo' = false)
for (const element of array1) {
  if (store.get('foo') {
    return
  }
  // do something here
}
```

Is there a better way to handle "state" in ElectronJS without react/vue?